# Could not get unknown property 'Download' for project ':OsmAnd' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, module, osmand

Error in this file **apply from: 'build-common.gradle'**

Error on these lines of code:

`task downloadDefaultWikivoyage(type: Download) { src 'https://creator.osmand.net/basemap/Default_wikivoyage_2.travel.obf' dest 'assets/Default_wikivoyage.travel.obf' onlyIfModified true }`

I am trying to import osmand module